# Why would I get a "CHttpRequest is unable to determine the request URI" when creating a migration?

Tags: plugin-development, migration

I have logged into the server and attempted to create a migration for my plugin.  However I get this output:

```
exception 'CException' with message 'CHttpRequest is unable to determine the request URI.'
```

The request is targeting "/craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:519".

```
Stack trace:
#0 /craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php(431): CHttpRequest->getRequestUri()
#1 /httpdocs/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php(816): CHttpRequest->getPathInfo()
#2 /httpdocs/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php(43): Craft\HttpRequestService->getNormalizedPath()
#3 /httpdocs/craft/app/framework/base/CModule.php(387): Craft\HttpRequestService->init()
#4 /httpdocs/craft/app/framework/base/CModule.php(103): CModule->getComponent('request')
#5 /httpdocs/craft/plugins/redactorclips/RedactorClipsPlugin.php(31): CModule->__get('request')
#6 /httpdocs/craft/app/services/PluginsService.php(136): Craft\RedactorClipsPlugin->init()
#7 /httpdocs/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php(53): Craft\PluginsService->loadPlugins()
#8 /httpdocs/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(165): Craft\ConsoleApp->init()
#9 /httpdocs/craft/app/framework/YiiBase.php(121): CApplication->__construct('/var/www/vhosts...')
#10 /httpdocs/craft/app/etc/console/yiic.php(76): YiiBase::createApplication('Craft\ConsoleAp...', '/var/www/vhosts...')
#11 /httpdocs/craft/app/etc/console/yiic(4): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
```

Comment: Do you get a full stack trace?  Can you share the entire yiic command you used to attempt to generate it?

Comment: I did get a full stack trace. Here is the command I used: " ./yiic migrate create Create_Relations Events".

Comment: Can you share the stack trace in the original post (redacting out any sensitive info you don't want to share)?

Comment: It is shared with sensitive info redacted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bug in our RedactorClips plugin, actually.  Just fixed it, so if you grab the latest from here (https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorClips), `yiic` still should run fine.

Comment: why is this a bug? I see in the change log that you wrapped some code in the plugins init() method in `if (!craft()->isConsole()) { ... }` (https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorClips/commit/8a28c357e4f9c8d5b5315cf27a7e26385d000bbf). Under what conditions should we plan to do the same in our own plugins?